# No result with SendKeys to IE8 using Selenium on BrowserStack

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-8, browserstack

I'm using Selenium to perform testing on BrowserStack, and have hit a problem while testing IE8.

I've found that when I target elements and then call `Click`, the full effect of the action is not being undertaken*.

Through trial-and-error I found that if I call `Click` twice then the expected action *is* undertaken.

However, one of the testing steps involves writing a number to a text field, and for this I have the following:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("...")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("...")).Clear();
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("...")).SendKeys(Keys.NumberPad1);
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("...")).Click();
```

But "1" never appears in the field. I can tell it never appears because I'm capturing screenshots after each step; I can see that the field gets highlighted (as the active element) and I can see the cursor inside the field, but no result from the method call.

Furthermore, I've even tried giving the field an ID and addressing it with

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtCountManual")).SendKeys(Keys.NumberPad1);
```

But with the same (lack of) results.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I may send a textual value to a field in IE8 using Selenium and BrowserStack?

* The "expected action" involves using Knockout.js to display a selected value in another element. So for example, I found that if I programmatically click a radio button and then take a screenshot, I can see that the radio button has been clicked but the action performed by Knockout.js has not taken place; if I click the element a second time *then* the Knockout.js action is performed. This double-clicking is not required when I manually test using IE8 via BrowserStack.

Comment: Try printing the text from the field by using `driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtCountManual")).getAttribute("value")` and check if you get empty or the value you input using Keys.

Comment: It returns an empty value.

Comment: Send a click event  to the input field before using sendKeys method. Hope it helps.

Comment: As you can see from the code in the OP, I *am* sending a click event to the input field before using sendKeys method. Furthermore, I also send one afterwards. It doesn't help.

Comment: After sending clear event, use click event. I had observed similar issue long back in IE browser and it did work for me. Still if it doesn't work, you can use javascript to enter the value.

Comment: You're right about using JavaScript - that's what I've implemented for now, but I'm still hoping someone can provide a definitive answer here to explain things because the JS solution seems a bit hack-ey.

Comment: Yes JS is bit hacky. I have seen many users reporting the same issue. Appears to be some bug with IE driver. I haven't been able to find the definitive answer/solution.

Comment: One more solution I found is using Actions class. `Actions act = new Actions(driver); act.sendKeys(element, "InputValue").perform()`.